# node.js executable hangs up unexpectedly

Tags: node.js, windows, executable

I created an executable using nodejs.
when I run the executable, it ,sometimes, hangs up at somepoint. however clicking CTR + C in the terminal makes the executable to continue.
this only happen on windows. on linux everything works fine.

Comment: There is a lot of information missing here, how did you create the executable as nodejs scripts are usually run through the interpreter.
What did you try to debug it, and what is the point at which it is hanging, is there an infinite loop possibly?
It something related to windows firewall for a webcall that different in linux, hard to help without more explicit info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Problem

This is probably related to windows `Quick Edit Mode`. The option makes the cmdlet randomly wait for user input and blocks until it gets it... I don't know what's the idea behind this. So instead `CTRL + C` you could basically press any key for continuing it. This happens with Windows Command line in general and is not related to `nodejs`.

##### Solution

- Start your program as usual
- right click the terminal window and open `settings`
- Disable `Quickedit-mode` setting
- => Problem should not occur anymore. As far as i know, the setting should persist.

(My Windows has german language. translations: `QuickEdit-Modus = Quickedit-mode` and `settings = Eigenschaften`
[image]

##### Other ideas

- Run your application with Windows-Task Scheduler
- Use another terminal e.g. `git bash`